# What is the most accurate location data I can get from an iOS App without explicitly asking for permissions?

Tags: ios

I don't need geolocation information but just enough to get an idea as to what city or state the user may live in. I have thought about using NSDate information and using the user's timezone, but this isn't quite specific enough. Is there anything I could use (on iOS8 and newer) that could help me better identify the location of the user without being too specific or invasive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If they have an internet connection, you can use their IP address. IPs can usually be geolocated to a specific city.

I run the [IPLocate.io](https://www.iplocate.io) service which provides geolocation data - it's free to use!

See our [docs](https://iplocate.docs.apiary.io) for info on how to call the API.